What materials to use to prevent damage from cat urine
I have a cat that urinates on the wall in my laundry room and mud room.
What materials do I use to renovate this area and protect from future pee?
Need recommendation for drywall, is there a type that’s moisture resistant?
Recommendations for baseboards? Anything that won’t absorb urine?
Any specific paint or primer to avoid absorbing before I can clean it?
Thank you

You could start with an enzymatic pet cleaner.  Can you simply keep the laundry room off-limits to the cat?  Supposedly vinegar repels cats, perhaps you can keep an open container of vinegar there.

Consider painting a band of clear polyurethane around the bottom of the wall and baseboards  the height of the cat. The finish will protect the wall, does not absorb odors  and is easy to clean.

You also may want to consider things like using PVC baseboard. Or fixing the cat, though that may not change habits once they are established.

Ceramic tiles with epoxy grout would be your best bet. A good place to use the big ones and have less grout exposed. You can get baseboard tiles if you want a baseboard look. You could do normal waterproofing behind the tile and use normal grout but then the grout will absorb some of the cat pee. Epoxy grout should not.
Otherwise some sort of impervious plastic wall overlay, typically sold for shower walls.
I suppose stainless steel would also work, but it's expensive and a bit more odd-looking (we had a stainless backsplash behind the stove in the house I grew up in, seemed all kinds of sensible to me, but it's "unusual" out of a commercial kitchen context.)
